USB flash drive freezes for few seconds while writing data
I bought a brand new USB flash device 2 weeks ago.
Since yesterday, I am having this issue. When I write data to it, it freezes with 100% activity and 0 data write speed for few seconds at a time.
Note:

I did bad sector check using Disk Genius. It didn't report any issue.

chkdsk /F /R i: didn't report any issue

Full format in Window completes but USB flash drive freezes several times during it (with 0 write speed / 100% activity).

USB flash drive is only 2 weeks old

I tried a different USB drive in my PC and didn't experience such problem

Same problem in safe mode too.


Note: The issue started yesterday and was not happening 2 weeks ago
The question is asking for an explanation of this phenomena, not for an explanation how USB Flash Drives differ from SSDs.

That's not at all unusual for flash drives.

This question is similar to: Why are USB flash drives so much slower than SSDs?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DrMoishePippik I have updated the question

@DrMoishePippik It was not happening before with same drive 2 weeks ago. Other USB flash drive don't have issue either

@JoepvanSteen They are different model but both are premium quality ones. I guess there is nothing I can do. Best to ask for refund because it's defective
